# Building ASP.Net Web API RESTful Service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, rest, restful-architecture

How to start learning ASP RESTful services?
What do I need to know before start learning RESTful services?

Any suggestions will be grateful.

Comment: Are you going to develop REST service using ASP.Net MVC? Then go with Web API 2. See more at http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Building+ASP.Net+Web+API+RESTful+Service

Answer (score 2):

You should refer to the Microsoft "Guide to Designing and Building RESTful Web Services" which provides a very comprehensive overview of the REST prerequisite knowledge such as HTTP, URI and then reviews REST and finally details WCF support for RESTful services.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx

After reviewing the Microsoft design guide, you should review the highly rated CodeProject article on REST.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services